# Execute java spring project from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Java Spring project, using tomcat, and I want to know how to run it with command line, today I only know using eclipse, I would like to run something like in Rails

```
rails s
```

How can I do that?

Comment: web applications must run in a container (like tomcat).  Either install the war file in Tomcat and run Tomcat or do as @DaveH says below, check out spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) - if the app is already built using Spring it will probably port pretty easily. It allows you to build the app as a jar file and it'll start it's own embedded servlet container to provide the environment for your app to run in.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it, if you have a Spring MVC project you could build a war file and deploy it as a web application on tomcat (put a war file to tomcat webapps dir and start a tomcat - you can do it with startup.sh file in tomcat bin directory).

If you have a Spring boot application you can package your application as jar/war and start it with `java -jar application.war` command.

Answer (score 0):

in springboot application we can use embedded servers like tomcat or jetty , just include corresponding entries in pom.xml and build war file.

for ex:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and then open cmd and run any of the command:
java -jar application.war

javaw -jar application.war